# Is the interior of a compact subset of a domain again a domain?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I am asking myself the following question:

> Let $G \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be a domain and let $K \subset G$ be compact with non-empty interior. Is  $\mathring{K}$ a domain?

Intuitively I would say yes, but I do not see how to rigorously prove it. Could you help me?

Comment: what is a domain in this context?

Comment: @SiddharthBhat A _domain_ is a connected open set...

Comment: This is even false if you assume $K$ to be connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider $G= \mathbb C$ and $K=\{z \in \mathbb C: |z| \le 1\} \cup \{z \in \mathbb C: |z-23| \le 1\}.$